# d3 hierarchy layout with custom value for non-leaf nodes

Tags: layout, tree, d3.js, visualization

d3 defines the hierarchy layout as a tree were leaf nodes have value and non-leaf nodes have children. The value of the non leaf nodes is automatically computed as the sum of the value of its children (see [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/layout/hierarchy.js#L30)).

I have slightly different needs. I want to define a tree were non-leaf nodes have a value too. The precondition is that the value of a non-leaf node is always greater or equal to the sum of the value of its children.

```
{
  "name": "parent",
  "value": 10, <-- I want to use this value, not 4+2 = 6
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "child1",
      "value": 2,
    },
    {
      "name": "child2",
      "value": 4,
    }

  ]
}
```

Graphically, I want to achieve a kind of icicle tree but the children will not always fill all the width of their parent node.

What would be the best solution to achieve this behavior ? I am new to d3 and I don't want to reinvent the wheel or create a new layout from scratch if it is not required.

Comment: It sounds like you would need to implement a new layout -- maybe reusing some the existing things, but I don't think that anything that's already there would fulfill your requirements.

Comment: That was what I was "afraid" of. It does not sound that difficult but I'm still surprised that this use case is not already addressed. Any input still welcome since I could write this logic directly inside my application, but if a new and more generic layout seems useful to someone else I could try to write it.